# SonarQube for VB.net 2.0

Tags: vb.net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am trying to find out a possibility to run SonarQube scan for VB.net 2.0 project. I use Visual studio 2005 to compile the code. I understand that SonarScanner for MSBuild doesn't support 2.0 Framework and currently MSBuild 14.0 and 15.0 are supported.  This project is not supposed to be upgraded as of now. Please advise if there is any workaround to setup Sonarqube with this current version. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried building your project from the command line using a newer version of MSBuild? The older MSBuild project format is still understood by newer versions of MSBuild, and you can use e.g. MSBuild 15 to build a project that produces an assembly that targets .NET Framework v2.0. If that works, then you should be able to use MSBuild 15.0 and the Scanner for MSBuild from the command line to do an analysis and push the results to SonarQube. You won't be able to see the issues inside VS, though, as VS2005 is pre-Roslyn.

Comment: Wat SonarQube version and edition do you use?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I use SonarQube version 6.7.4